# How to display the default tooltip on the html file of a n Altair Chart generated by Python Altair Chart.save(file.html)?

Tags: javascript, python, altair

After saving the chart produced in Python Altair in HTML format, it appears the default tooltip is not available in the HTML version.

When I run this code in Jupyter, I can see the tooltip in Jupyter Output. But when I open the bar.html file in a browser, there is no tooltip shown when I hover over the chart.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

barley = data.barley()

chart = alt.Chart(barley).mark_bar().encode(
    x='variety:N',
    y='sum(yield):Q',
    color='site:N',
    order=alt.Order("site", sort="ascending")
)
chart.save('bar.html')
chart
```

I read the Vega Lite documentation on tooltip. I added the script tag for the tooltip but I still could not make it work. What did I do wrong? Is there an easier way to add the default tooltip? Thanks in advance.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-tooltip"></script>

....

var embed_opt = {"mode": "vega-lite", tooltip: {theme: 'dark'}};
vegaEmbed("#vis", spec, embed_opt)
        .catch(error => showError(el, error));
```

Comment: Can you please show a complete example of the Python code you ran, describe what you expected to see, and how it differed from what you actually saw?

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear. I took an example (see code below) from the tutorial and saved the chart as HTML. In the Jupyter notebook, the tooltip appears but not on the HTML file that I saved. Any way to make the default tooltip appear on the HTML as well?

Comment: import altair as alt  <br/>
    from vega_datasets import data  <br/>

    barley = data.barley()  <br/>

    chart = alt.Chart(barley).mark_bar().encode(  <br/>
        x='variety:N',  <br/>
        y='sum(yield):Q',  <br/>
        color='site:N',  <br/>
        order=alt.Order("site", sort="ascending")  <br/>
    )  <br/>
    chart.save('bar.html')  <br/>
    chart  <br/>

Comment: Sorry I am not sure how to paste the code here with the correct markdown. Newbie here.

Comment: You can't paste formatted code blocks in comments. I would suggest updating the question.

Comment: @jakevdp Thanks. I have updated the question.

Comment: When I run that code I don't see tooltips in either the Jupyter notebook version or the saved html version. If you want to control tooltips within a plot, you can use the ``tooltip`` channel; see https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/scatter_tooltips.html for an example.

Comment: Thanks @jakevdp .
Sorry, what I meant was the Jupyter Lab and not the Jupyter notebook. 
I'll take a look at the link you gave. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default tooltips are only supported by Vega-Lite version 3. Altair currently supports Vega-Lite version 2.6.

The reason you saw the default tooltips in JupyterLab is because the jupyterlab vega extension mistakenly included Vega-Lite 3 in its most recent release. That mistake is being corrected here: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/5342